# Calculator not working if you enter a letter instead of a number

Tags: python, if-statement, calculator

My Calculator is half working. I really put my brain in it but I cant figure out why its not working. Can someone help me?

```
number1 = input("Enter first number: ")
number2 = input("Enter second number: ")
operator = input("Enter the operation character: ")
result = number1 + operator + number2

if operator == '+':
    result = int(number1) + int(number2)
elif operator == '-':
    result = int(number1) - int(number2)
elif operator == '*':
    result = int(number1) * int(number2)
elif operator == '/':
    result = int(number1) / int(number2)
if number1.isdigit() == True:
    print (result)
elif number2.isdigit() == True:
    print(result)
else:
    print("Enter a number.")
```

It's printing the calculated value, but if you enter a letter instead of a number.
For example:
Enter a first number: 5
Enter a second number: f
Now it should print "enter a number". But im getting this message istead
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

```
if number1.isdigit() == True:
    print (result)
elif number2.isdigit() == True:
    print(result)
**else:
    print("Enter a number.")**
```

Comment: Where is the `"enter a code"` part?

Comment: If I enter a letter `a` instead of a number `3` I get the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`. That seems to be how the program should work. What is your exact input that's causing the program not to work the way you'd like?

Comment: How is it that you have an `input` function and an `input` variable? Python is a one-namespace language; functions and variables do not have separate spaces like in Common Lisp or Unix Shell and such.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i edited my post, sorry. do you understand now?

Comment: You appear to be asking "why does `int(number1)` cause a `ValueError` exception when `number1` has a non-numeric value?" - but that's the expected behaviour. The meaning of a `ValueError` is ["Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) - `int('a')` just makes no sense, so a `ValueError` is raised, it's unclear what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're checking whether the input consists of numbers only, but only *after* you tried using it. You need to check *before* the error would be raised by using it in a call to `int()`.

Comment: i just wanted to be printer "enter a number" when someone enter symbol or a letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lines like these:

```
if operator == '+':
    result = int(number1) + int(number2)
```

*Before* lines like these:

```
if number1.isdigit() == True:
    print (result)
elif number2.isdigit() == True:
    print(result)
else:
    print("Enter a number.")
```

So, if `operater` is indeed a `+`, Python will try to evaluate `int(number1) + int(number2)` and fail if `number1` or `number2` is not the string representation of a number.

This raises a [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) (as it should) and a raised exception that isn't caught in a `try .. except ..` block will cause your program to terminated. You cannot continue with uncaught exceptions.

Either you should check *first* and then try to convert these strings, or you should catch the exception.

Also, you seem to expect your code to continue running after the mistake is made, so you'll need some sort of loop that keeps the program running until the user enters some input that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood what you what but I think this solves the problem

```
number1 = input("Enter first number: ")
number2 = input("Enter second number: ")
operator = input("Enter the operation character: ")
result = number1 + operator + number2

if number1.isdigit() == True and number2.isdigit() == True:
    if operator == '+':
        result = int(number1) + int(number2)
    elif operator == '-':
        result = int(number1) - int(number2)
    elif operator == '*':
        result = int(number1) * int(number2)
    elif operator == '/':
        result = int(number1) / int(number2)
    print (result)
else:
    print("Enter a number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting on coding, I suggest you to use this as a reason to search and learn on some few important concepts that will help you to get going.

First, you must validate your inputs before doing anything else with them. In your case, validate that your first and second numbers are actually valid integers, right after they are input. As it is the same validation to be done on both, you can create a function so you can reuse the logic.

```
def input_number():
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num.isdigit():
        return int(num)
    else:
        print("Invalid number.")
        return input_number()
```

Here, I check if the input is valid (`isdigit` is true), and then I return the value already converted to `int`. If it is not, I call the same function again, and repeat the process. This is called [recursion](https://realpython.com/python-recursion/).

You should also validate the operator, because it is only valid among a few options.

```
def input_operator():
    while True:
        op = input("Enter the operation character: ")
        if op in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
            return op
        else:
            print("Invalid operator.")
```

Here I used a different technique. It is called [`while` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html), and it will repeat the execution inside it until the condition is not True, or until it is explicitly broken (in this case, with a `return` statement).

Now, you have to add both function definitions on top of your code, then adjust you logic accordingly.

```
number1 = input_number()
operator = input_operator()
number2 = input_number()

if operator == "+":
    result = number1 + number2
elif operator == "-":
    result = number1 - number2
elif operator == "*":
    result = number1 * number2
elif operator == "/":
    result = number1 / number2

print (result)
```